# Magento Custom coupon for subtotal

Tags: coupon, cart-rule

I need to have 2 value caps in coupon:

1. Minimum cart value
2. If the coupon offer is a % off then we should have the facility to capture the maximum discount that can be passed to customer

Example: offer is 15% off on minimum purchase of 2000 and maximum discount of 4000
I should have the facility to cap the minimum purchase value where the coupon will be applicable secondly I should be able to cap the maximum discount that can be passed to customer should not be more than 4000